# Node Express i18next - How to send locale text to client side js file?

Tags: node.js, express, locale, i18next

I have i18next setup in Node.js server side. What is the best practice to use i18next.t() in client side javascript files? I've already set up Express to render server side variables to be used in .ejs files. However, I can't transfer them to the js files that are imported in ejs.

Some possible ways I've thought of:

1. Export and load i18next that was initialized in the server to the client.
2. I know the <%= %> variables for ejs work in inline scripts. However, I'm avoiding to have them for content security policy. Perhaps there is a way to send this over to the js file?
3. Load and initialize i18next on the client-side again. I've tried this and it works, but then there are duplicated locale files for both server and client.
4. Export the locale files by specifying path. EX
   `app.use('/locale', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'locale', {{lng}}.json)));`

```
// app.js

const i18next = require('i18next');
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend');
const middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');
i18next.use(Backend)
    .use(middleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        detection: detection_options,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        backend: {
            loadPath(lng, ns) {
                if (lng === 'zh' || lng === 'zh-HK' || lng === 'zh-TW') {
                    return path.join(__dirname, 'locales/zh-hant.json');
                } else if (lng === 'en-US') {
                    return path.join(__dirname, 'locales/en.json');
                }
                return path.join(__dirname, 'locales/{{lng}}.json');
            }
        }
    })
app.use(middleware.handle(i18next));
```

```
// index.ejs

<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <%= t('locale-text-from-en.json-goes-here') %> // this works well
  </h1>

<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
// index.js

console.log(t('locale-text-from-en.json-goes-here')) // how to use i18next.t() here?
```

Answer (score 0):

To use i18next on the client you need to install the i18next package via npm or yarn on the client. Or download i18next library via their CDN https://unpkg.com/i18next/dist/umd/i18next.js.

i18next has many extensions for your project, like react-i18next for react project, jquery-i18next for jquery project.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very proficient in Javascript. I do use jquery for some parts, but my question is: can i18next on server and client (say, jquery-i18next) share the same locale file and how can I do that?

Comment: Yes it can share.Also it depends on your requirement, if you would translate your API response in server and have the client render it as static text it is valid too. But our strategy is we usually return translate key in the API response and have the client translate it according to user's preferred language.

Comment: If you are translating in Server, you would need to know the user's preferred language. Usually you can set in the request header and use this while translating in server.